# Azure C# Mobile Services Status Route

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

I was having issues with some of the default routes interfering with my intended routing, so in my WebApiConfig/Register(), I cleared the config.Routes and created my own. This works for all of my api calls, but it broke Azure's status checking.

How can I either

1. Clear the routes without clearing the Azure added one(s?)
2. Add the status route back in.

I miss the smiley face website!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you **can** do that: save the routes you want to maintain, clear the routes, then add them back. Or just remove the ones you want removed. You can easily find the route names using the debugger (see below for an example) or using some quick reflection to do that while the service is running in Azure.

[image: Default routes from a mobile service]

Why **you probably shouldn't** remove them: the mobile services platform is constantly updated in Azure, and before that is done a series of tests is performed to ensure that it doesn't break the majority of the scenarios. I'm not 100% sure, but I could bet that having the routes which are added by the platform removed is not one of them, so you could find your service broken down the road if some other component is added that depends on one of the routes you removed being present.

So, as @HenrikFrystykNielsen mentioned in his answer, try to find out what kind of conflicts you're having, and whether they can be resolved in a way that doesn't potentially cripple the service.

Comment: Hi @carlosfigueira (and Henrik)!

I agree - I would like to remove the default WebAPI routes and keep the Azure ones. My web services don't look like the typical WebAPI calls, by design. I want to remove all of the "By Convention" routes and only use my own, custom routing. 

Henrik asked what happened that I felt the need to call Clear() - I get "Multiple actions were found that match the request"... on most of my service calls, but without the "convention" based routes, everything works correctly.

Comment: OK, so I think that what I have now is better. Do you see anything wrong with:  
    config.Routes.Remove("MS_attributerouteWebApi");  
    config.Routes.Remove("DefaultApis");  
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");

Answer (score 1):

what are the conflicts you see?

You are right that we do use the /status and /diagnostics endpoints for monitoring and report if they are not there (in fact we do add them back so strictly speaking I think you can ignore the frowny

Henrik